# Why is my SQL request not returning the good values

Tags: mysql, sql, dbeaver

I have a very simple table with 5 lines like this :

```
server_id         |prefix|
------------------|------|
539535394385905845|+     |
320924748948348332|-     |
209324893085080324|?     |
145011317933728096|/     |
134729843343337892|!     |
```

My table construction is :

```
CREATE TABLE `servers_settings` (
  `server_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prefix` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

My (very simple) request is :

```
SELECT * FROM servers_settings
```

And it returns me the following result :

```
server_id         |prefix|
------------------|------|
539535394385905845|+     |
539535394385905845|+     |
320924748948348332|-     |
209324893085080324|?     |
145011317933728096|/     |
```

The problem, as you can see before, it's the values returned by the request are not the same as my basic table, but it should.
I'm using DBeaver, and the connection to my database is well. It's very very strange that bug.

Comment: Are you asking why the order is different? Results aren't ordered unless you specify. You also seem to have created a duplicate `server_id`. Is that real, or just a typo? Specify _why_ the values are 'bad'. Just leaving that up to inference is insufficient.

Comment: @underscore_d the order is not different, where do you see a different order? There is no duplicate `server_id` but the request returns a duplicate, this is my problem, why this duplicate and the last value is not returned...

Comment: Are you querying the right database? right table? Is the logic used to display the code correct?

Comment: @Gugu72 what does this returns: `SELECT count(*) FROM servers_settings`

Comment: @SalmanA I've only one database, and one table, so yes these are the right. And yes, it should return me my table content, because I select all from this table.

Comment: @VBoka It returns `count(*)|
--------|
       5|`

Comment: Well, I can not repeat that : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75cde1880663ff73a692ad1a239777b5 :)

Comment: what does this return: `SELECT * FROM servers_settings where server_id = '134729843343337892'`

Comment: All that is missing are the insert queries. The select will display what's in the db, so this is what is in it. The question is how it got there. Looks like a loop issue, duplicate first entry, and the last entry is missing.

Comment: Try another client, like MySQL Workbench, to rule out a bug in DBeaver displaying the result.

Comment: @VBoka It returns nothing, this is strange... EDIT: After testing, the value was not existing but it was in the database..., so I removed it and it's ok, but the first value is repeated twice...

Comment: --> WAIT, I removed the first value and the last, and now it's working, no duplicates and no missing, these values were strange I suppose... :/

Comment: Rows in relational databases represent unordered sets.

Comment: @Strawberry and this explains the duplicate value and one value missing ?

Comment: No, but I can't replicate that error

Comment: @Strawberry Said 1 hour ago I removed the values, and it works now.